# how to install R packages "RNetCDF" and "ncdf" on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, installation, deb, netcdf

I would like to use the R packages RNetCDF and ncdf in Ubuntu.

When I try `install.packages('RNetCDF')` or `install.packages('ncdf')`, I get similar errors:

```
...
ncdf.c:3:20: fatal error: netcdf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ncdf.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf’
...
Warning message:
In install.packages("ncdf") :
  installation of package ‘ncdf’ had non-zero exit status
```

The packages `libnetcdf6` and `netcdf-bin` from the Ubuntu repository are installed. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: you need to install the `-dev` of those packages to get the headers that are required to compile the package.

Comment: @Justin thanks. the only additional package required for `ncdf` was `libnetcdf-dev`

Comment: for `RNetCDF`, `udunits-bin` and `libudunits2-dev` are also required

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the `-dev` of those packages to get the headers that are required to compile the package.  In this case, you need `libnetcdf-dev`, `udunits-bin` and `libudunits2-dev`

Comment: In order to install the ncdf4 package (the update to the ncdf package), I also needed to run `sudo apt-get install netcdf-bin`

Comment: Does anyone know why this still necessary? It's 7 years since this answer, and it still needs some kind of perm fix.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, libudunits2-dev package was needed.

`sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev`

Since I installed NetCDF from source, I had to manually specify the locations of *lib* and *include* folders

```
install.packages("/home/user/Downloads/RNetCDF_1.6.1-2.tar.gz", 
repos = NULL,
type="source",
dependencies=FALSE,
configure.args="--with-netcdf-include=/usr/local/netcdf-4.2.1-build/include --with-netcdf-lib=/usr/local/netcdf-4.2.1-build/lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, since your initial issue is in R, and the fix is applied outside of R.  I initially was trying to do

> install.packages("libnetcdf-dev"), which didn't work.

instead, from outside of R:   sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS one can install the ncdf4 package (which [supersedes ncdf](http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/%7Epierce/ncdf/)), including all dependencies, with the bash (shell/terminal) command `sudo apt install r-cran-ncdf4`. Similarly for RNetCDF you can use `sudo apt install r-cran-rnetcdf`.

Comment: Thanks, very useful for my problems installing RNetCDF