# Unable to access udunitslib while installing RNetCDF package in R

Tags: r, fedora, netcdf

Hi I am trying to install RNetCDF package in RStudio. But when I'm trying to do so I am getting the error message

```
-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
```

So then I tried

```
install.packages('udunits2', configure.args=('--with-udunits2-lib=/opt/lib'))
```

since my libudunits2.a is in `/opt/lib`

error message is same again; and also

```
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
```

I have tried again by giving the location of udunits.h

```
install.packages('udunits2', configure.args=('--with-udunits2-lib=/opt/lib/ --with-udunits2-include=/opt/include'))
```

Error this time is:

```
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
```

I am using Fedora 23. Any help will be dearly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try this first http://nco.sourceforge.net/#bld You may also need to try some dev versions as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319698/how-to-install-r-packages-rnetcdf-and-ncdf-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you! This helped (http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/udunits/msg00467.html)