# Issue installing "udunits2" in R 3.6.1

Tags: r, linux

'udunits' is a dependency I need to install but when I try to install via `install.packages("udunits2")` I get the error:

```
-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
     You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIB
     environment variables.
     If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
     It is required for this package.
```

I followed the solutions provided in [Install udunits2 package for R3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287164/install-udunits2-package-for-r3-3), but I still get the same issues.

I installed libudunits2-dev using `sudo apt install libudunits2-dev` and the package is installed as when I call `dpkg -L libudunits2-dev` I get:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/converter.h
/usr/include/udunits.h
/usr/include/udunits2.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudunits2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/udunits.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/ANNOUNCEMENT
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/BACKLOG
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/udunits2lib.html
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/udunits2lib.pdf.gz
/usr/share/info
/usr/share/info/udunits2lib.info.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudunits2.so
/usr/share/doc/libudunits2-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Even when I install udunits2 via `install.packages("udunits2", configure.args = '--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2')`, the same issue occurs.

Installing on Ubuntu 20.04.1
R 3.6.1 in anaconda environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.